# Show data from Firebase in RecyclerView on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I currently have implemented RecyclerView, but my CarView does not show the data.

These are my current data in Firebase:

[image: Three records in Firebase]

But the RecyclerView shows all three CardViews, but without the records:

[image: Screenshot of CardView without logs]

These are the files I'm using:
DomiciliarySearchFragment.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.didierzuniga.domix.R;
import com.didierzuniga.domix.adapter.OrderAdapterRecyclerView;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.HashMap;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class DomiciliarySearchFragment extends Fragment {

    @Bind(R.id.recycler_order) RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public DomiciliarySearchFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_domiciliary_search, container, false);
        showToolbar(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_search), true, view);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        new GetDataFromFirebase().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

        // Read from the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("order");

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                HashMap<String, String> values = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new OrderAdapterRecyclerView(values));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                System.out.println("Failed to read value." + error.toException());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private class GetDataFromFirebase extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }

    public void showToolbar(String tittle, boolean upButton, View view){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(tittle);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(upButton);
    }
}
```

OrderAdapterRecyclerView.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.didierzuniga.domix.R;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class OrderAdapterRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderAdapterRecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
    private HashMap<String, String> values;
    public OrderAdapterRecyclerView(HashMap<String, String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_order,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.fromm.setText(values.get(position));
        holder.too.setText(values.get(position));
        holder.moneyToPayy.setText(values.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return values.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView fromm;
        private TextView too;
        private TextView moneyToPayy;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            fromm = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.from);
            too = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.to);
            moneyToPayy = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.moneyToPay);
        }
    }
}
```

Model: Order.java

```
public class Order {
    public String uid;
    public String oFrom;
    public String oTo;
    public String oHeader;
    public String oDescription;
    public String oMoneyToPay;
    public String oAuthor;
    public boolean completed;

public Order(){

    }

public Order(String oFrom, String oTo, String oHeader, String oDescription, String oMoneyToPay, String oAuthor) {
    this.oFrom = oFrom;
    this.oTo = oTo;
    this.oHeader = oHeader;
    this.oDescription = oDescription;
    this.oMoneyToPay = oMoneyToPay;
    this.oAuthor = oAuthor;
    this.completed = false;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public void setUid(String uid) {
    this.uid = uid;
}

public String getoFrom() {
    return oFrom;
}

public void setoFrom(String oFrom) {
    this.oFrom = oFrom;
}

public String getoTo() {
    return oTo;
}

public void setoTo(String oTo) {
    this.oTo = oTo;
}

public String getoHeader() {
    return oHeader;
}

public void setoHeader(String oHeader) {
    this.oHeader = oHeader;
}

public String getoDescription() {
    return oDescription;
}

public void setoDescription(String oDescription) {
    this.oDescription = oDescription;
}

public String getoMoneyToPay() {
    return oMoneyToPay;
}

public void setoMoneyToPay(String oMoneyToPay) {
    this.oMoneyToPay = oMoneyToPay;
}

public String getoAuthor() {
    return oAuthor;
}

public void setoAuthor(String oAuthor) {
    this.oAuthor = oAuthor;
}

public boolean isCompleted() {
    return completed;
}

public void setCompleted(boolean completed) {
    this.completed = completed;
}
}
```

¿What I need to do to be able to display the registers in each CardView?

Thank you!

Comment: you should get dataSnapshot.getChildren() first and then get all the records one by one in a loop. Each child under children will be Order item then. ChildEventListener is more proper for this case. Another issue is dont create new Adapter everytime data values change. instead set adapter values and use notifydatasetchanged

Comment: You could use a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to make things easier https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database

Answer (score 1):

In DomiciliarySearchFragment.java /onDataChange, 
Can you confirm that hashmap has been correctly populated?

I had  a similar problem,  but the reason was that the data was not stored correctly in the collection

Answer (score 1):

Thanks uguboz, I should have use dataSnapshot.getChildren(), and get all the records one by one in a loop

```
        rv = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_order);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        orders = new ArrayList<>();
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        adapter = new OrderAdapter(orders);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        database.getReference().child("order").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                orders.removeAll(orders);
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Order order = snapshot.getValue(Order.class);
                    orders.add(order);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Thank you everyone.